# select only if all sub-objects match a condition

Tags: sql

There is an Orders table and a Content table. 
Each order contains multiple items stored in content table with join of order number.
Order table contains order number.
Content table contains multiple items with each record having order number and item status columns.
I need to a query that would output distinct order numbers where all of the items should have status done.

I tried this

```
SELECT O.O_NUM FROM ORDER O, CONTENT C WHERE C.STATUS=DONE
```

but this will return order number even if any one content item status is done.

Comment: What database do you use? Oracle, MySQL ... Also please provide some sample data and what you expect to get from that data... Also show us the columns for tables OREDER and CONTENT

Comment: Hi Anon, is DONE a field?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hint: NOT EXISTS (or GROUP BY, HAVING, etc.)

Comment: Hints from me: Do not use reserved words as table names, don't forget join criterias

Comment: can you please tell me what type of data you have and what type of data you expect it ?

Comment: Is `DONE` a column or a value?

Comment: it's oracle database. Cant share specific columns but the columns I shared are all that are used in joins. Done is a value I want to use as must required condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Orders.OrderNumber
FROM Orders
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Content
                   WHERE Orders.OrderNumber = Content.OrderNumber
                     AND Content.Status != 'Done' )
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some context by explaining how your answer solves the problem, instead of posting code-only answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25089837)

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select o.orderno
from orders o inner join
     content c
     on c.orderno = o.orderno
group by o.orderno
having sum(case when c.status <> 'done' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```